# Compare 2 Columns in CSV and Create a New Column If it matches

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that is doing a SQL query of several databases.
It spits the results out into a CSV file on my desktop.
I would like the Powershell script to compare 2 of the columns then create a new column if they match up.

It just saves me the time having to do the compare every time in excel.

I just dont know enough about powershell to do this.

Current results in the CSV is like this.

```
    Name      PhoneNumber       PhoneNumberInDB2    
   Person 1    1112223333          1112223333
   Person 2    4445556666          7778889999
```

I would like the script to modify the csv to do this.

```
    Name      PhoneNumber       PhoneNumberInDB2    Match?
   Person 1    1112223333          1112223333         Y
   Person 2    4445556666          7778889999         N
```

Ive seen several scripts how to compare multiple csv and make a new one... but I would rather just modify the one that gets created from the  SQL query.

If it helps... here is a copy and paste from the actual CSV file I edited the phone number to protect customer... I am viewing the csv in exel.

```
    ID  Phone   DB2Phone
5521350 1112223333  1112223333
```

From Notepad:

```
"ID","Phone","PhoneID"
"5521350","1112223333","1112223333"
```

Comment: That's not a CSV though

Comment: I dont see how its not a CSV..

Comment: @Bnd10706 - if it was a CSV, then the values would NOT be centered beneath the column headers. no matter what the delimiter was, that layout is not what one gets from a CharacterSeparatedValue file. ///// what do you get from `$QueryResult.GetType()`?

Comment: i formatted to be viewed better.

Comment: @Bnd10706 - PLEASE, only post sample data as it really is. you waste your time ... and other folks time with falsified sample data.

Comment: I apoligize, there are customer phone numbers and company data in the csv.. i edited it anyways to protect that. If it really helps to not center columns i will. it was simply made for visual understanding and honestly should not change anything.

Comment: Open the csv in notepad and copy and paste it

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I added a copy and paste with only the edited phone... i dont see how it changed anything.

Comment: @PatrickMcvay Thank you... I dont use CSV too often and normally open in Excel.

Comment: @Bnd10706 - the notepad version is the real one. thank you for posting that ... it makes a good deal more sense of your Question. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly maybe you can use `Select-Object` to add the property to the incoming objects.  It sounds like the 2 properties you're comparing are within the same object at any given time. So, you should be able to get this down to a single pipe...

Something like:

```
$Data = Import-Csv "file.csv" |
Select-Object *,
    @{Name = 'Match'; Expression = { If( $_.PhoneNumber -eq $_.PhoneNumberInDB2 ){ 'Y' } Else { 'N' } } }
```

> Note: I removed the "?" on the new property (column) name.

If you need to re-export to re-export to the same Csv file, simply pipe `$Data` to  `Export-Csv` :

```
$Data = Import-Csv "file.csv" |
Select-Object *,
    @{Name = 'Match?'; Expression = { If( $_.PhoneNumber -eq $_.PhoneNumberInDB2 ){ 'Y' } Else { 'N' } } }

$Data | Export-Csv "file.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Above assumes you want to re-use the file name if you want to change the name you can put it in a single pipeline like:

```
Import-Csv "file.csv" |
Select-Object *,
    @{Name = 'Match?'; Expression = { If( $_.PhoneNumber -eq $_.PhoneNumberInDB2 ){ 'Y' } Else { 'N' } } } | 
Export-Csv "file_new.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Note: This revision doesn't require `$Data`.  Because it's all on the pipeline it's more memory efficient. Though that's not normally an issue unless the file is very big.

Comment: This does seem to be running, but I am not getting any results or errors. There is no column in the CSV named match if that is ok...

Comment: OK i tried it in a new PS Script and it still did not compare... sorry i just dont know enough about PS to understand why not

Comment: I played with this a few times in both running the script after the SQL separately and its still not getting any results. im not sure if this csv classifies these column titles from SQL as headers or not.

Comment: The way it's written it's storing the objects in a variable. so it's not going to generate any output and certainly not going to change the file.  I will update the answer with a slightly modified version to recreate the file.

Comment: ok thank you... i have multiple files that are 4000+ lines long and this will save me a bunch of time in the future

Answer (score 1):

```
$Data = Import-Csv "file.csv"
ForEach ($obj in $Data) {
$hashtable = [ordered]@{}
ForEach ($property in $obj.PSObject.properties.name) { $hashtable[$property] = $obj.$property }
$hashtable["match?"] = If ($obj.'PhoneNumber' -eq $obj.'PhoneNumberInDB2') {"Y"} Else {"N"}
$Data = $Data -ne $obj
$Data += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Hashtable
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.. i do get an error when I tried this. Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At Phone List.ps1:97 char:1
+ $Data += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Hashtable
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: What is your csv file format? Seems like you're not importing a correct file.

Comment: I see the method of this approach, but I think it's the long way.  There's no reason to synthetically create a hash table especially to later convert to an object. PowerShell has several native methods to append additional properties to objects.  You should also avoid the += operator for appending arrays.

Comment: agreed, your approach is much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

here's yet another way to do the job ... [*grin*] what it does ...

- fakes reading in a CSV file
  when you are ready to do this for real, simply replace the entire `#region/#endregion` block with an `Import-CSV` call.
- iterates thru the collection
- creates a new object with the desired properties
- compares the two phone numbers and saves that to the `SamePhoneNumber` property
  you can replace those `False/True` items with `N/Y` if wanted. just swap the comment markers on line 19 & 20. if you will be doing more processing, the `False/True` stuff works better than mere letters since it gets auto-converted to a boolean in PoSh.
- sends the new object out to the `OutStuff` collection
- shows that on screen

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a CSV file
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$InStuff = @'
"ID","Phone","PhoneID"
"5521350","1112223333","1112223333"
"2020202","2020202020","2000000002"
"3030303","3030303030","3030303030"
"4040404","4040404040","4000000004"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
#endregion >>> fake reading in a CSV file

$OutStuff = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ID = $IS_Item.Id
        Phone = $IS_Item.Phone
        PhoneId = $IS_Item.PhoneId
        # if you want `N/Y` instead of `False/True`, swap the comment markers for lines 19 & 20
        SamePhoneNumber = $IS_Item.Phone -eq $IS_Item.PhoneId
        #SamePhoneNumber = @('N', 'Y')[$IS_Item.Phone -eq $IS_Item.PhoneId]
        }
    }

$OutStuff
```

output with booleans ...

```
ID      Phone      PhoneId    SamePhoneNumber
--      -----      -------    ---------------
5521350 1112223333 1112223333            True
2020202 2020202020 2000000002           False
3030303 3030303030 3030303030            True
4040404 4040404040 4000000004           False
```

output with `N/Y` ...

```
ID      Phone      PhoneId    SamePhoneNumber
--      -----      -------    ---------------
5521350 1112223333 1112223333 Y              
2020202 2020202020 2000000002 N              
3030303 3030303030 3030303030 Y              
4040404 4040404040 4000000004 N
```